# Is it possible for Sequelize to include a table from another database in the same query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've got a two MySQL Schemas both with a table called User as I want to have a SSO application with multiple microservices. I can't seem to get Sequelize to generate the correct SQL for my needs.

I've tried adding the 'schema' attribute to my model definitions in Sequelize, but it tries to use 'schema_name.schema_name.table_name' instead of 'schema_name.table_name'. I'm unsure whether the schema attribute works for MySQL.

SuperUser.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    'User',
    {
      id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      username: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
      first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
      last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
      company: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      // tried to add schema: super_schema
      underscored: true,
      timestamps: true,
      paranoid: true,
    },
  );
  User.associate = function(models) {};
  return User;
};
```

SubUser.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    'User',
    {
      id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      role: {
        type: VARCHAR(45),
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      underscored: true,
      timestamps: true,
      paranoid: true,
    },
  );
  User.associate = function(models) {
    const { super } = models;
    User.belongsTo(super.models.User, { as: 'Super', foreignKey: 'id' });
  };
  return User;
};
```

My query is

```
const user = await db.sub.User.findOne({
      include: [
        {
          model: db.super.User,
          as: 'Super',
          where: {
            username: 'someUsername',
          },
        },
      ],
    });
```

I believe the problem lies in how I'm creating the Sequelize instances, I'm creating an instance for each schema connection. So Sequelize doesn't know that `db.super.User` is different from `db.sub.User` when written in Javascript.

The problem lies in the INNER JOIN it generates.

It generates

```sql
INNER JOIN `users` AS `Super` ON `User`.`id` = `Super`.`id`
```

I'd like it to generate

```sql
INNER JOIN `Super`.`users` AS `Super` ON `User`.`id` = `Super`.`id`
```

Comment: MySQL is unusual in that it lets you join outside of the database. Postgres and others, by comparison, only allow joining within the database but from different schemas. I'm not sure Sequelize can handle this without you having to write out the query long-form.

Comment: I've noticed MySQL is different in terms of handling 'schema' whereas MySQL treats databases & schema the same. I'm unsure whether I should switch to Postgres due to this or whether I should continue to use MySQL as I feel that with scaling, having separate databases for each micro-service would be preferable. But I'm more than open to reasons why switching to Postgres would be preferable.

Comment: Postgres does a lot of things that you'd expect from a more "enterprise" database, like having a proper schema system. Prior to Postgres 9.0 most people used MySQL because it was faster and had a lighter learning curve. Now Postgres is arguably as fast or faster in many cases, especially Postgres 11+, which makes it a compelling alternative to MySQL. If you need schemas, you probably need Postgres.

Comment: @tadman Interesting, I'll definitely have a look at Postgres and toss up my options. Could Sequelize do what I'm trying to do if I was using Postgres?

Comment: With Postgres if you've got several schemas, then yes, you can join schema to schema. The only limitation is leaving the database to do that.